# resulting array shape when dropping dimension in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

Trying to understand how numpy selects elements when indexing in more than 2 dimensions.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
x[:,:,0].shape #(2, 3)
```

In writing `x[:,:,0]` I am selecting all the elements along the "depth", all the "rows" and the first column. When thinking about this visually I would have thought numpy would return something with a shape of (2,3,1) but instead the last dimension is dropped. This is reasonable but how does numpy populate the result? Ie in this example, why does `x[:,:,0]` result in the elements [0,12] forming the first column. Just trying to figure out the general logic which for some reason I am not comprehending at the moment.

Comment: It may help if you start with a 1d array, `x[0]`.  Then a 2d array, `x[:,0]` or `x[0,:]`, etc.  numpy tries to be consistent across all dimensions.  Also explore indexing with a list, or slice.

Comment: good idea - i may just need to re-read the docs, not sure why i'm not getting this when it's obviously simple

Comment: @Alex Might help to think of left to right in the index as "first to last" axis. And then the last axis is the one printed left to right when you display your array. Take every first element from that last axis. Now don't forget that we don't want to take off the brackets from the other axes (since we take full slices for them). That gives your result. Note you could also write this as `x[..., 0]`.

Comment: @miradulo could you expand on that please? i'm not sure i am clear on what you mean

Comment: I am not sure how :P perhaps hpaulj's suggestion of starting with a 1d array and working your way up may be more helpful.

Comment: makes sense, that's what i'm doing now. hoping maybe there is a very clear doc somewhere that just says "this happens, then this happens, then this" when a dimension is dropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General NumPy indexing is complicated, but this is still the easy case. I've always felt that it helps to think in terms of how indexing the result corresponds to indexing the original array.

The result of `x[:, :, 0]` is an array such that for any indices `i` and `j`,

```
result[i, j] == x[i, j, 0]
```

Similarly, if you index a 5D array `a` as `a[:, 1, :, 2, :]`, the result is such that

```
result[i, j, k] == a[i, 1, j, 2, k]
```

Comment: I like this train of thought: could you give some intuition about what is happening when a dimension is dropped (i get the `(i,j)` point that you made)? ie in the ex i provided it retains the original two dimensions.. to make the new array fit into this shape you have to transpose since what used to be depth is now rows and what used to be rows is now columns.

Comment: @Alex: NumPy data representation isn't like a list of lists, where removing or reordering dimensions requires physically rebuilding the whole thing. NumPy just computes new shape and stride information so it knows where to look in the original data buffer to find `result[i, j]`.

Comment: It may help to [read about](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.html#internal-organization-of-numpy-arrays) how NumPy array data representation works.

Comment: good idea - will take a look at the internals.. haven't gotten to that yet. might solve my confusion